# How to use parameters for salesforce API connection while deployment of Logic app?

Tags: azure, deployment, salesforce, azure-logic-apps

I have developed a Logic app and want to deploy it using parameter file.

When we use `service bus connector` into logic app `we have service bus connection string` so we can make it as a `parameter for service bus connection string`.

But while using `salesforce connector` it will `ask for login` into `designer panel` and generate a API connection for `salesforce`.

But while deployment i `do not find any connection string or login credential url for salesforce connector`.

> I wonder how it will work for other resource groups while deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Can your Logic App reference the existing salesforce connector?  Salesforce connectors need to be authenticated; however, once authenticated I believe you can reference it in your ARM template by using something like the following in the Logic App:

```
         "$connections": {
        "value": {
          "salesforce": {
            "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', 'CONNECTION REGION', '/managedApis/', 'salesforce')]",
            "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('salesforce_Connection_Name'))]",
            "connectionName": "[parameters('salesforce_Connection_Name')]"
          }
```

You can deploy the connection in the same template with something like this:

```
 {
      "type": "MICROSOFT.WEB/CONNECTIONS",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('salesforce_Connection_Name')]",
      "location": "centralus",
      "properties": {
        "api": {
          "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', 'INSERT REGION', '/managedApis/', 'salesforce')]"
        },
        "displayName": "[parameters('salesforce_Connection_DisplayName')]",
        "nonSecretParameterValues": {
          "token:LoginUri": "[parameters('salesforce_token:LoginUri')]",
          "salesforceApiVersion": "[parameters('salesforce_salesforceApiVersion')]"
        }
      }
    }
```

You'd have to pass in the LoginURI as a parameter which if you have multiple Salesforce and Azure environments would be a good thing to reuse the same template with different parameters.

Comment: But how to authenticate it at runtime while deployment?

Comment: Unfortunately I believe you need to authenticate manual the first time.  After that the ARM deployment will only do deltas and since we are referencing/redeploying the same ARM template if there aren't updates to the connection it should stay authenticated