# Team collaboration for large, ARM templates in repos

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps

So, we have the ARM templates in tens of thousands of lines and the resultant merge conflicts through our AzDO pipelines, etc. We are starting to look into solutions. What are others doing? Our ARMs are all for Logic Apps. Is "[linked templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates)" the way to go? Other solutions? Recommended vendors? Open source? Lessons learned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are making progress with Azure linked templates and from here and other communities, no better alternative has emerged. The smaller, linked templates are reducing the time spent doing merge conflicts on our end, so there is a return on the investment.

Answer (score 1):

If your only issue is merge conflicts - how is this an ARM template question? doesnt matter if its an ARM template or c# file. A merge conflict is still a merge conflict. Establish something like gitflow or trunk based development model and use that.

Comment: I consider it an ARM template questions since linked ARM templates are a possible solution and linked ARM templates won't help with C# files.

Comment: why would they. they would have merge conflicts as well. again, we would not be able to help you to break down templates into smaller bits. you can use linked templates if you choose to, but I dont see how that would help. Again, I don't see a question. Use linked templates if you so desire. ARM Templates are just a text file. In the end the question is: "we fail to edit the text files without merge conflicts, how can we fix that". use common developer practice to collaborate on development

Comment: We use git-flow. We have multiple developers making multiple branches off the same file. changes that make it to master can cause merge conflicts to resolve for later PRs. This is fine, just takes time. In a C# solution with multiple classes per file, someone may go to a model of one class per file to avoid the same issue. We are looking for a best practice or methodology that is similar for large ARM templates.

Answer (score 0):

So if using Logic apps what is causing the length of the ARM templates to be so long? Is there a possibility of breaking them up?  If the templates are long related to the number of connectors you are using which can happen here is [a way to reference existing connections in ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59369058/how-to-use-parameters-for-salesforce-api-connection-while-deployment-of-logic-ap/59377468#59377468)

Comment: Our ARM templates represent the complex business rules for EDI processing: EDIFACT, X12, VDA, etc. Such a process can such as receiving a large Purchase Order, such as one that would fill a truck. Scores of actions are typical. So they are broken up, a typical ARM can cover a score of LAs or more where one LA calls another conditionally.